# Change brightness programmatically on Android emulator

Tags: java, android

I use a code to change the brightness programmatically on Android.
The code work when launch on an Android phone but on the Android emulator I get the following error :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: calculator.moi.android.fr.tp4 was not granted  this permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.
```

However int the manifest I have :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure that if you are running on Marshmallow 6.0 you didn't press decline when asked for permision?

Comment: Yes I run Marshmallow 6.0 on the emulator and no permission was asked

Comment: Check in Application Manager in Settings. Maybe that was some missclick?

Comment: You mean AVD ? If so I double check all parameters and it looks great for me